# Recuperar un valor de php, y enviarlo mediante un boton, a otro php

Tags: php, mysql, post, botón, base-de-datos

la consulta es simple, pero mis conocimientos de php son casi nulos.

La idea es que un boton de un modal, acceda a un php (idcontenedor.php) que ya tiene un valor impreso( Por ej: 4100), lo use y llame a otro php (insertarDB) pasandole ese valor para que haga la insercion en la base.

```html
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#getid").load("idcontenedor.php");
    setInterval(function() {
     $("#getid").load("idcontenedor.php");
    }, 500);
   });
  </script>
```

Aca la parte del boton...

```html
    <h5>Confirma que desea accionar las luminarias de la Cancha de 11?</h5>
      <form action="cancha11.php" method="post" >
       <textarea name="id" id="getid" style="visibility:hidden"></textarea>
       <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >CONFIRMAR</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
       </div>
      </form>
```

Como veran, funcionar funciona, uso un textarea oculto. Pero visualmente, queda feo, ya que deja un espacio en blanco.

La idea es que el boton "confirmar" haga la insercion en la base, sin tener que llamar a otro php, y que pueda mantener el "4100" oculto, sin el uso del textarea, como cuando se usa el post, que en php lo captura en una variable, aca igual.

Answer (score 0):

Para que no llame a otro php podrias hacer una validación del mismo formulario, osea:

que te mande a la pag actual y hagas una validación por ejemplo:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<textarea name="id" id="getid" style="visibility:hidden"></textarea>
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="confirmar">CONFIRMAR</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
</div>
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['confirmar'])){

y metas el código que inserta...

}
?>
```

y para enviar un campo oculto en vez de usar el `<textarea name="id" id="getid" style="visibility:hidden"></textarea> y te rompa la vista podrias usar un campo <input type="hidden" name="id />`